# How to create multiple files by getting the filename from the list in text file (java)?

Tags: java, io, nio

For example, there is a file `subjects.txt`:

- Java
- Python
- Perl
- Php

Which functions should be used to create four text files with names `Java.txt`, `Python.txt`, `Perl.txt`, `Php.txt` using list from `subjects.txt`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: before asking this kind of questions, take a look on Java API also google should be your best friend

Answer (score 2):

Read in the original file using [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)), then iterate over the resulting list and use [Files.createFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) to create a new file based on the words being iterated over.

Something like the following should work, provided you add in the try-catches to handle any exceptions.

```
final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/path/to/textFile.txt"));

lines.forEach(line -> {
    Files.createFile(Paths.get("C:/path/to/" + lines + ".txt"));
});
```

Comment: good idea, but the solution is on Java 8.. i think for learning purposes ( i assume topic starter is new to java) needs to learn by himself with pretty easy Java 7 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File f = new File(subjects.txt);
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

wile(s.hasNext)
{
    String name = s.nextLine();
    name += ".txt";
    PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter(name);
}
```